# "ImportError no module named conf.urls", but the name is django.conf.urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am getting an odd error that doesn't show up on google, it says:

```
ImportError at /scripts
No module named conf.urls

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named conf.urls
Exception Location: ...scriptcity/fakedir/scripts/urls.py in <module>, line 1
```

The file in question is:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from fakedir.scripts import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$',  views.index,     name='index'),
    url(r'^bash/$',  include('scripts.bash',  namespace='bash')),
    url(r'^autokey/$',  include('scripts.autokey',  namespace='autokey')),
    url(r'^django/$',  include('scripts.django',  namespace='django')),
    url(r'^python/$',  include('scripts.python',  namespace='python')),
    url(r'^ruby/$',  include('scripts.ruby',  namespace='ruby')),
    url(r'^practice/$',  include('scripts.practice',  namespace='practice')),
    url(r'^bashrc/$',  views.access_bashrc,  name='bashrc'),
)
```

I had the `django.conf.urls` as `from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include`, and same error. I don't get why it is ignoring the 'django' part at the beginning. What can cause this problem? Thank you

Comment: What is your django version? do you run project by using **virtualenv**?

Comment: I have 1.8.2, and I usually do not use virtualenv. I'm not using it here either